# Is there a way to overlay image above frame?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

```
mapframe =tk.Frame(root,bg="#756754")
mapframe.place(relwidth=0.45,relheight=0.79, relx =0.03, rely=0.05)

#map image
image = Image.open("Map.jpg")
mapimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image.resize((540, 610), 
Image.Resampling.LANCZOS))
label = Label(mapframe, image=mapimage, bg='#4a4135')
label.image = mapimage
label.pack()

and

pointer = ImageTk.PhotoImage ( file = "draggable.png",)
pointerimge = table.create_image(10, 10, anchor=NW, image=pointer,)

def move(event):
"""Move the sprite image with a d w and s when click them"""
if event.char == "a":
    table.move(pointerimge, -10, 0)
elif event.char == "d":
    table.move(pointerimge, 10, 0)
elif event.char == "w":
    table.move(pointerimge, 0, -10)
elif event.char == "s":
    table.move(pointerimge, 0, 10)
```

im trying to make the pointer appear above the frame but it hides behind
any ideas ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ztcgn.jpg)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] we can run to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

well apparently frames are on top of the program so i just removed the frame and inserted map as :

```
mapimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage (file = "Map.jpg")
mapimge = table.create_image(290, 190, anchor=tk.NW, 
image=mapimage)
```

Comment: Should provide in your own question instead of putting an answer here.